# Loading a Nifti through Nibabel and using the shape function

Tags: python, nifti, mri, nibabel

I have a nifti file **1.nii.gz**

[image]

**Now, i never dealt with nifti files**.

So, just opening it using this software i realized that a nii.gz is a sort of container that contains **3 arrays of 2d pictures**. In fact, if i scroll the mouse i can see 448 2d picture for the "direction" labeled in the picture as 1, 448 2d pictures for the "direction" 2 and 25 2d pictures for the "direction" 3.

After this, i opened the shell and i tried to use this nii.gz with Nibabel library

```
import nibabel as nib
img = nib.load(1.nii.gz)
```

But, if i type

```
img.shape
```

i get (448,448,25) as result, so it seems that this .nii.gz is a 3d matrix and not a container with 3 arrays of 2d pictures. Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Nifti` is a medical images format, to store both images, and companied data, the images are usually in grayscale, and they are taken as slices, each slice with a different cross-section of the body.

**They store all the slices in the same array**, and sometimes they take the slices during different times so **sometimes they add a fourth dimension** to the array.

So to show the images, or manipulate them, you can slice them and see the images inside.

> In your case the shape of your data (448,448,25) tells that:
>
> There are **25** images (slices) with dimensions 448 x 448

```py
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change the path to your path
path = 'path to img.nii.gz'
Nifti_img  = nib.load(path)
nii_data = my_img.get_fdata()
nii_aff  = my_img.affine
nii_hdr  = my_img.header
print(nii_aff ,'\n',nii_hdr)
print(nii_data.shape)
if(len(nii_data.shape)==3):
   for slice_Number in range(nii_data.shape[2]):
       plt.imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice_Number ])
       plt.show()
if(len(nii_data.shape)==4):
   for frame in range(nii_data.shape[3]):
       for slice_Number in range(nii_data.shape[2]):
           plt.imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice_Number,frame])
           plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you reply. I really appreciate it. If the file 1.nii.gz contains 25 images  with dimensions 448x448 (== the images relative to the lateral view of the head, labeled with the number 3 in the picture from my post), where the 448 slices of label 1 and the 448 slices of label 2 are extracted from ?

Comment: @AleWolf that's another question, if you want me to answer that question you have to provide a sample of your Dataset, so I can see and understand what's exactly inside, sometimes they put the images in one nifti, and the mask(ground truth) on another one, so I can't judge without a sample of your data.

Comment: Here a sample https://easyupload.io/368cv3 Thank you infinitely , i would really appreciate if you explained clearly these kinds of details since i never worked with nifti files and i know very little about them

Comment: @AleWolf I have checked your file, it contains only images, no labels inside, the labels might be on another file, this file is a group of grayscale images.

Comment: For labels, i intended the labels I have drawed with the red color in the picture of my initial post . I write again my last question: If the file 1.nii.gz contains 25 images with dimensions 448x448 (== the images relative to the lateral view of the head, labeled with the number 3 in the picture from my post), where the 448 slices of label 1 and the 448 slices of label 2 come from ?

Comment: @AleWolf sorry for misunderstanding, now I think that I have got your question, the other images in your post I guess they are coming from the software that you are using, it makes 3D reconstruction of the brain, and reprojects that on the other planes.

Comment: Mhm, that means that generally a nifty file is an array of 2d slices ? In this case, an array of 25 slices (with dimension 448x448) ?

Comment: @AleWolf yes in your case there is no time frames, only slices.

Comment: Time frames means : "the same MRI exam (with the same number of slices), but taken at different moment" ?

Comment: @AleWolf yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the full sized image in plot

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_load = nib.load('imgx/label0002.nii.gz').get_fdata()
print(test_load.shape)

#this will plot full siz size 
plt.imshow(test_load[:,:,test_load.shape[2]//2])
plt.show()
```