# How to save and read NIfTI file

Tags: python, image-processing, nifti, nibabel

I am trying to save a NIfTI file but I am not sure if I am doing everything right.

```
Recon_Img[:, :, d-1, :] = MeanImg[:,:,ITERATIONS-1]/NumberOfSlices


recon_filename = 'ReconstructedImage.nii.gz'
    
recon_image = nib.Nifti1Image(Recon_Img, reconstructed_aff, reconstructed_hd)
nib.save(recon_image, recon_filename)
```

The first row is part of a loop, where `d` iterates through `NumberOfSlices`.

This generates a .nii.gz file but I do not know how to open and check if the reconstructed image is correct or not.

Comment: Sorry, but why are you creating a nifti file if you don’t have a tool that reads nifti files?

Comment: @Vin please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please refer to the manual of [nibabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html), additionally you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61834369/8618242)

Comment: fsleyes is a nifti viewer written in Python: https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FSLeyes